# How to change location of Genymobile folder from C:\Users\MY-PC\AppData\Local\Genymobile\. to my desired location?

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

I've installed the Genymotion in my C drive & When I start it, it automatically creates a folder viz. Genymobile & it sub-folders (which stores data about the device that has been added)  @ C:\Users\MY-PC\AppData\Local\Genymobile...

(It is by Default & works fine), but I need to keep this folder(Genymobile) in another drive, How may I do that ?

I've moved the above folder to my desired location & changed the Path for Virtual Box & Misc from the settings of Genymotion & restarted, but It didn't worked means the old device was not being listed & new folder Genymobile gets created at C:\Users\MY-PC\AppData\Local\Genymobile.

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution to my problem.

**MY PROBLEM :**

My Problem was by default when I add a devices in GenyMotion all its related file get saved in appdata folder of C drive at C:\Users\MY_PC\AppData\Local\Genymobile. as a result size for C drive gets increased & lead me to low disk space.

I decided to keep the Genymobile folder in a different drive, & When I open Genymotion there was no device in genymotion & a fresh folder "GenyMobile" along with its sub-folders & file got recreated in C drive at C:\Users\MY-PC\AppData\Local\Genymobile.

Thus, I was unable to make some space in my C drive by moving the Genymobile folder from appdata & start a device from new location.

**MY SOLUTION :**

1. Move the folder Genymobile to your desired location e.g. move  from C:\Users\MY_PC\AppData\Local\Genymobile to D:\Genymobile.
2. Open GenyMotion
3. Go To Settings -> Virtual Box
4. Check the path given for virtual devices there from previous to new one
5. For e.g. if old path is C:/Users/Your_PC_Name/AppData/Local/Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/, new path should be D:/Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/.
6. Make sure all your devices are at D:/Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed.
7. Find the .virtualBox folder in your system, generally it is found at 
   C:\Users\Your_PC_Name.VirtualBox- (in windows OS)
8. Find file "VirtualBox.xml" 
   if you find  "VirtualBox.xml-prev" or  "VirtualBox.xml-tmp" instead of
   VirtualBox.xml
   8.1  make a copy of the "VirtualBox.xml-prev" file and renamed the copy to 
    "VirtualBox.xml"
9. Go to MachineRegistry TAG  & update src value for each MachineEntry i.e. your Genymotion Virtual Device.

Now, Restart GenyMotion. It is working for me.

Comment: For folks out there. These instructions are great AND SIMPLE. It might SEEM complex, but is really simple to do and can save tons of time and effort if you need to move existing vm's to a different disk.